# Individual Blogs

Tags: user-profile, blog

Is it possible for each person in SharePoint to automatically  have their own blog? I found http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1368-how-to-create-a-blog-site-and-manage-blog-posts-in-sharepoint-2010/ but don't seem to have the option udner the content tab on the user profile.

Answer (score 1):

Each user can create a blog subsite within their My Site if they desire.  Or you could go "Wordpress MU like" and create a web application where self service site creation is enabled and allow users to create blogs under a web app like blogs.ourcompany.com.

Comment: The blog tempalte seems to be missing in "My Site".

Comment: It's a default template that should be available under Site Actions, Create, Sites and Workspaces (2007) or Site Actions, New Site, Blog (2010)

Answer (score 0):

You can use feature stapling to automatically provision a Blog sub-site as the MySites are provisioned, or you can provision the subsites via a console application or powershell for any existing site.

If you are looking to highlight the blog posts in the User Profiles I would probably add a web part to the person.aspx page (Overview tab) or add an additional tab that focuses on this content.